# "Can't copy! Making copies of Window or Scope instances is not supported"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to create an angular module and am recieving this error.

I'm using webpack and typescript.

**Angular Code:**

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import * as router  from '@uirouter/angularjs';

export let app = angular.module('timeApp', [
    require('@uirouter/angularjs')
]);
```

**Webpack config:**

```
const path = require('path');

const config = {
    entry: {
        app: [
            './Client/app.module.ts'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/dist/')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.tsx?$/,loader: 'ts-loader',exclude: /node_modules/}
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Why is this error occurring?

- **AngularJS**: 1.6.6
- **Typescript**: 2.6.2
- **Webpack**: 3.9.1

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the same error with a project running without webpack, now using webpack and first time I see this very strange error. I'm not using typescript though

Comment: Any luck with the issue?

Comment: Sorry, I think I figured out a way around this, but it was long after posting this. I no longer know the solution, and will probably have tot tackle it again on the next project...